# Работа с api сайта в python

Tags: python, python-3.x, requests

Нужно реализовать поиск wi-fi сетей (а именно паролей от них) через api сайта https://3wifi.stascorp.com.
Постоянно появляется ошибка:

```
{"result":false,"error":"form","time":0.0020060539245605}
```

Вот код:

```
import requests

url = 'https://3wifi.stascorp.com'
data={"key": "23ZRA8UBSLsdhbdJMp7IpbbsrDFDLuBC", "essid": "Free_WiFi"}
headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json"}
r = requests.post("http://3wifi.stascorp.com/api/apiquery",
data=data,
headers=headers
)


print(r.text)
```

[image: Скрин кода и ошибки]

Comment: Замените `data=data` на `json=data`

Comment: @andreymal не помогло...

Comment: Судя по [документации](https://3wifi.stascorp.com/apidoc), параметр `bssid` должен быть обязательно. `essid` является опциональным, **если** задан `bssid`.

Comment: @МихаилМуругов Не думал что я настолько тупой) Но спасибо за помощь, всё зароботало)